# How to build a tabbed video player like Facebook

Tags: javascript, html, carousel, video-player

Facebook has a new video player window where the video player stays fixed above three tabs: info, comments, and up next.

I have re-created the design but how do I create the carousel-playlist under the “Up next” tab that corresponds to the above fixed video player?

Here is a picture of Facebook. The code is below it.

[image: up now tab]

```
<html>
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8"/>
 <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link href="css/main1012018.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

</head> 

<body>  
 <div id="page" >

 <!--/LOGO PANEL/-->    
 <div id="logo" >
 <img class="name" background-color="transparent" height="20px"  alt=""/>
</div>


<h3>Monitor</h3>
  <p>The fixed Video Player is always randomly playing one of the videos from the Video tab below. If you click one of the buttons below it changes the content for that tab</p>

<div id="controls"></div>
<div id="Profile" class="tabcontent"></div>

 <div class="tab">
  <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'OnNow')">On Now</button>
  <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'Beans')">Videos</button>
 </div>

<div id="menu2">
 <div id="OnNow" class="tabcontent">
  <h3>OnNow</h3>
  <p>Displays the title and description of what is actively playing in the video player.</p>
</div>

<div id="Beans" class="tabcontent">
  <h3>Video</h3>
  <p>This tab contains rows each with videos that corresponds to that row that I can scroll through like Netflix/Amazon/Hulu. When you select a video/push play then the above video player is interuppted and plays the video. Each Row is a following Genre: Newest, Top 10(you follow), Friend's Channel, Int'l </p>
</div>  
</div>  

<script>
function openCity(evt, cityName, skipClass) {
var i, tabcontent, tablinks;
tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent");
for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
  tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";
}
tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablinks");
 if(!skipClass) {
   for (i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++) {
      tablinks[i].className = tablinks[i].className.replace(" active", "");
   }
   }

  document.getElementById(cityName).style.display = "block";
  evt.currentTarget.className += " active";
  }

  $('.link').click(function(event){
  event.preventDefault();
  var url =$(this).html();
  $("#videoDiv").html('<iframe width="400" height="400" src="'+url+'?wmode=transparent" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>');

 })
 </script>
 </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: Show us what you have tried, where you're facing problems and we'll be able to help you more.

Comment: My bad, thought I did, forgot to indent. :)

Answer (score 1):

Here's a demo from w3schools: https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/w3css_tabulators.asp

```html
<div class="w3-bar w3-black">
  <button class="w3-bar-item w3-button" onclick="openCity('London')">London</button>
  <button class="w3-bar-item w3-button" onclick="openCity('Paris')">Paris</button>
  <button class="w3-bar-item w3-button" onclick="openCity('Tokyo')">Tokyo</button>
</div>

<div id="London" class="city">
  <h2>London</h2>
  <p>London is the capital of England.</p>
</div>

<div id="Paris" class="city" style="display:none">
  <h2>Paris</h2>
  <p>Paris is the capital of France.</p> 
</div>

<div id="Tokyo" class="city" style="display:none">
  <h2>Tokyo</h2>
  <p>Tokyo is the capital of Japan.</p>
</div>

<script>
  function openCity(cityName) {
    var i;
    var x = document.getElementsByClassName("city");
    for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) { x[i].style.display = "none"; }
    document.getElementById(cityName).style.display = "block"; 
}
</script>
```

### Edit

If you're after a none JS solution, where it only uses HTML & CSS, you could look at something like this CodePen I've just found: https://codepen.io/oknoblich/pen/tfjFl

```css
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,600,700");
@import url("https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css");
*, *:before, *:after {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html, body {
  height: 100vh;
}

body {
  font: 14px/1 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  color: #555;
  background: #eee;
}

h1 {
  padding: 50px 0;
  font-weight: 400;
  text-align: center;
}

p {
  margin: 0 0 20px;
  line-height: 1.5;
}

main {
  min-width: 320px;
  max-width: 800px;
  padding: 50px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: #fff;
}

section {
  display: none;
  padding: 20px 0 0;
  border-top: 1px solid #ddd;
}

input {
  display: none;
}

label {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 0 -1px;
  padding: 15px 25px;
  font-weight: 600;
  text-align: center;
  color: #bbb;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
}

label:before {
  font-family: fontawesome;
  font-weight: normal;
  margin-right: 10px;
}

label[for*='1']:before {
  content: '\f1cb';
}

label[for*='2']:before {
  content: '\f17d';
}

label[for*='3']:before {
  content: '\f16b';
}

label[for*='4']:before {
  content: '\f1a9';
}

label:hover {
  color: #888;
  cursor: pointer;
}

input:checked + label {
  color: #555;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  border-top: 2px solid orange;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
}

#tab1:checked ~ #content1,
#tab2:checked ~ #content2,
#tab3:checked ~ #content3,
#tab4:checked ~ #content4 {
  display: block;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 650px) {
  label {
    font-size: 0;
  }

  label:before {
    margin: 0;
    font-size: 18px;
  }
}
@media screen and (max-width: 400px) {
  label {
    padding: 15px;
  }
}
```

```html
<h1>Responsive CSS Tabs</h1>

<main>
  
  <input id="tab1" type="radio" name="tabs" checked>
  <label for="tab1">Codepen</label>
    
  <input id="tab2" type="radio" name="tabs">
  <label for="tab2">Dribbble</label>
    
  <input id="tab3" type="radio" name="tabs">
  <label for="tab3">Dropbox</label>
    
  <input id="tab4" type="radio" name="tabs">
  <label for="tab4">Drupal</label>
    
  <section id="content1">
    <p>
      Bacon ipsum dolor sit amet beef venison beef ribs kielbasa. Sausage pig leberkas, t-bone sirloin shoulder bresaola. Frankfurter rump porchetta ham. Pork belly prosciutto brisket meatloaf short ribs.
    </p>
    <p>
      Brisket meatball turkey short loin boudin leberkas meatloaf chuck andouille pork loin pastrami spare ribs pancetta rump. Frankfurter corned beef beef tenderloin short loin meatloaf swine ground round venison.
    </p>
  </section>
    
  <section id="content2">
    <p>
      Bacon ipsum dolor sit amet landjaeger sausage brisket, jerky drumstick fatback boudin ball tip turducken. Pork belly meatball t-bone bresaola tail filet mignon kevin turkey ribeye shank flank doner cow kielbasa shankle. Pig swine chicken hamburger, tenderloin turkey rump ball tip sirloin frankfurter meatloaf boudin brisket ham hock. Hamburger venison brisket tri-tip andouille pork belly ball tip short ribs biltong meatball chuck. Pork chop ribeye tail short ribs, beef hamburger meatball kielbasa rump corned beef porchetta landjaeger flank. Doner rump frankfurter meatball meatloaf, cow kevin pork pork loin venison fatback spare ribs salami beef ribs.
    </p>
    <p>
      Jerky jowl pork chop tongue, kielbasa shank venison. Capicola shank pig ribeye leberkas filet mignon brisket beef kevin tenderloin porchetta. Capicola fatback venison shank kielbasa, drumstick ribeye landjaeger beef kevin tail meatball pastrami prosciutto pancetta. Tail kevin spare ribs ground round ham ham hock brisket shoulder. Corned beef tri-tip leberkas flank sausage ham hock filet mignon beef ribs pancetta turkey.
    </p>
  </section>
    
  <section id="content3">
    <p>
      Bacon ipsum dolor sit amet beef venison beef ribs kielbasa. Sausage pig leberkas, t-bone sirloin shoulder bresaola. Frankfurter rump porchetta ham. Pork belly prosciutto brisket meatloaf short ribs.
    </p>
    <p>
      Brisket meatball turkey short loin boudin leberkas meatloaf chuck andouille pork loin pastrami spare ribs pancetta rump. Frankfurter corned beef beef tenderloin short loin meatloaf swine ground round venison.
    </p>
  </section>
    
  <section id="content4">
    <p>
      Bacon ipsum dolor sit amet landjaeger sausage brisket, jerky drumstick fatback boudin ball tip turducken. Pork belly meatball t-bone bresaola tail filet mignon kevin turkey ribeye shank flank doner cow kielbasa shankle. Pig swine chicken hamburger, tenderloin turkey rump ball tip sirloin frankfurter meatloaf boudin brisket ham hock. Hamburger venison brisket tri-tip andouille pork belly ball tip short ribs biltong meatball chuck. Pork chop ribeye tail short ribs, beef hamburger meatball kielbasa rump corned beef porchetta landjaeger flank. Doner rump frankfurter meatball meatloaf, cow kevin pork pork loin venison fatback spare ribs salami beef ribs.
    </p>
    <p>
      Jerky jowl pork chop tongue, kielbasa shank venison. Capicola shank pig ribeye leberkas filet mignon brisket beef kevin tenderloin porchetta. Capicola fatback venison shank kielbasa, drumstick ribeye landjaeger beef kevin tail meatball pastrami prosciutto pancetta. Tail kevin spare ribs ground round ham ham hock brisket shoulder. Corned beef tri-tip leberkas flank sausage ham hock filet mignon beef ribs pancetta turkey.
    </p>
  </section>
    
</main>
```

Comment: I uploaded my code. What I'm trying to do is adds a video player adove the tabs but have the video carousel located under the video tab